# the onSubmit method is executed when I press a different button inside the form

Tags: angular, forms, onsubmit

I have a list of buttons with images inside the form. Pressing an image button executes the onSubmit method and I don't know why. Its supposed to only assign the image to the user's avatar value... If someone can explain that to me... Thanks!

```
<form class="col-md-6 form-style" #editProfileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editProfileForm)">
... 
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="surname">Avatar</label>
                <img [src]="'/assets/images/' + user.avatar +'.png'" width="35%" height="45%" alt="Icono de avatar">
                <div class="row" id="avatar-content">
                    <div *ngFor="let img of images" class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
                        <button class=" btn btn-light alignCenter" (click)="user.avatar = img">
                 <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/assets/images/' + img + '.png'" alt="Card image cap">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="form-group center">
                <input type="submit" value="{{saveBtn}}" class="btn btn-info" id="btnOk"
                    [disabled]="editProfileForm.invalid">
            </div>
</form>



onSubmit(form) {
    this.saveBtn = "Guardando..."
    this._userService.update(this.token, this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.status == 'success') {
          console.log(response);
          this.status = 'success';
          ....
```

Comment: This is default browser form behaviour. Set a type=“button” on the inner button - that should solve it.

Comment: Ok! it works thanks!!! I'm a student and I'm starting with angular and these things drive me crazy jejejeje thank u!!

Comment: Cool. Have fun building!